# How to calculate compositions when the numbers cannot be greater than a certain value?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of $k$-compositions of a positive integer $n$ is ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$, and its number of $k$-weak compositions is ${n+k-1}\choose{k-1}$.

However, how to calculate the corresponding compositions when we restrict that the numbers of the sequence cannot be greater than a certain value?

For example, suppose we have the list of all possible tickets with numbers of $6$ digits, where each digit can be a value between $0$ and $9$, and we want to calculate in how many of them their sum is $20$. (Since they are ticket numbers, as in a lottery, they can start with zeros on the left). The result should be the $6$-weak compositions of $20$ with the restriction that the values cannot be greater than $9$.

Comment: The idea is to apply inclusion-exclusion after *deliberately* putting 10 in one or more cells, if possible. Here it should be quite simple.

Comment: Do you mean numbers with six digits or strings with six digits, that is, can the first digit be zero?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My bad. I meant strings with six digits, so the first can be zero.

Answer (score 1):

One way is through recursion.  Let $N(k,m)$ be the number of $k$-weak compositions of $m$ into numbers in $\{0,\ldots,9\}$.  I don't know the answer immediately, but I can deduce
$$
N(k,m)=\sum_{i=0}^9 N(k-1,m-i)
$$
(by choosing the first number as one of $0,\ldots,9$) and the boundary conditions $N(1,i)=1$ when $i \in \{0,\ldots,9\}$ and  $N(1,i)=0$ otherwise.

And we can implement this e.g. in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) via:

```
NumComps:=function(k,m)
  if(m<0) then
    return 0;
  fi;

  if(k=1) then
    if m in [0..9] then return 1; fi;
    return 0;
  fi;

  return Sum([0..9],i->NumComps(k-1,m-i));
end;;
```

And if we run `NumComps(6,20);` we get `35127`.

Oh, and we can check the number via brute force.  The compositions are given in GAP by `Filtered(Tuples([0..9],6),R->Sum(R)=20);` which has size `35127`.